# How to select just one Toggle in LazyVGrid

Tags: swiftui, toggle, lazyvgrid

I use LazyVGrid to show set of data and as one column I'd like to use Toggle view to allow multiple lines selection. If I do it like this

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(data, id:\.id) { record in
            Toggle("", isOn: $selected).onChange(of: selected) { sel in
                print(record.id!)
            }
            Text("\(dateFormatter.string(from: record.start!))")
        }
    }
}
```

then (of course) all rows are selected or unselected being all binded to selected @State var. What's best practice here to allow individual lines selection?
Thanks.

Comment: Put the Toggle part in an own struct View with the `@State var selected` declared in it. So each row creates an own View with its own selected state var.

Comment: Thanks, it helped.